# MySql Identify the row in each group.

Tags: mysql

Set of data that needs to be sorted with column 1 showing on the first record but not remaining records.  I could add another column with boolean to determine which is first record.  The desired result below.

```
+--------+------------+-------+
| type   | variety    | price |
+--------+------------+-------+
| apple  | gala       |  2.79 | 
|        | fuji       |  0.24 | 
|        | limbertwig |  2.87 | 
| orange | valencia   |  3.59 | 
|        | navel      |  9.36 | 
| pear   | bradford   |  6.05 | 
|        | bartlett   |  2.14 | 
| cherry | bing       |  2.55 | 
|        | chelan     |  6.33 | 
+--------+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. In order for anyone to answer this question, you'll need to provide more information - what query are you currently using?  What does your table structure look like? What have you tried already?

Comment: What is your sample data with table structure ? Your question is also a bit unclear. Please explain further

Comment: This is something that it is generally more appropriate to handle at the client code layer; it _can_ be done in a query, but such queries end up being unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Your requirement can't be done on database side.  Do it in the application.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT `type`, `variety`, `price`
FROM (
   SELECT IF(@prev != t.`type`, t.`type`, '') AS `type`
      , t.`variety`, t.`price`
      , @prev := t.`type` AS actualType
   FROM theTable AS t 
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @prev := '') AS init
   ORDER BY t.`type`, t.`variety`, t.`price`
) AS subQ
```

It's been a while since I did something like this, but this is the general idea.

- The `init` subquery is just used to initialize the @prev session variable.
- The IF uses the "last seen" type to determine whether to show the type.
- The expression aliased as `actualType` updates the @prev session variable for the next row processed.
- The ORDER BY is needed to order the rows so that the @prev works out appropriately; in some cases I've had to put the ORDER BY in a deeper subquery `(SELECT ... FROM theTable ORDER BY ...) AS t` to make sure it is not applied after the expressions involving @prev.

Comment: Upvoted, but FWIW there is no need to put the query inside a subquery, except to exclude the fourth column.

Comment: @BillKarwin agreed, that outermost sub-querying is just to omit the fourth column; I assume if this kind of display work is being done in a query, the final results should be considered the final display.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, this is best done within the client as this is an issue of presentation, but you can technically achieve what you are looking for using the [ROW_NUMBER](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) windowed function and a CASE statement. I don't have a MYSQL instance handy, but the following should work.

```
WITH T as (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY type ORDER BY 1 ) rownum,
        type, 
        variety,
        price
    FROM products )
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN rownum = 1 THEN type ELSE '' END type,
    variety,
    price
FROM t;
```